# Angular5 canActivate() async function unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, canactivate

Can anyone help me with this.. New to unit test.. Thanks
Facing issues with Assync data

```js
export class ClassGuard implements CanActivate {         
      isLoaded: boolean = false;  
      constructor(private router: Router, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {}

      waitForUserToLoad(): Observable<boolean> {    
        return this.store.pipe(select(fromUser.sGetUserIsLoaded));   
      }

      canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {    
        return this.waitForUserToLoad().map(loaded => {   
          if (loaded) {   
            return true;   
          } else {   
            this.router.navigate(['']);   
          }   
        });   
      }   
    }
```

Can't explain much as new to this.. 
I've looked into and considered many jest unit tests, but have been unable to find a suitable option to remain fully understanding about this.

Comment: What is actually happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i want to write test case for given code.. Expected expect(classGuard.canActivate()).toEqual(true);